# How to get the class of the clicked element?

Tags: jquery

I can't figure it out how to get the `class` value of the clicked element.

When I use the code below, I get `"node-205"` every time.

jQuery:

```
.find('> ul')
.tabs(
{
    selectedClass: 'active',
    select: function (event, ui) {
        //shows only the first element of list
        $(this).children('li').attr('class');
    },
    cookie: { expires: 0 },
    fx: fx
})
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="tabs">
  <li class="node-205"></li>
  <li class="node-150"></li>
  <li class="node-160"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: your question is rather unclear... are you using any jquery plugin?

Comment: If it's a clicked item, shouldn't you be using the click() function to bind the event and get the class ?

Maybe I didn't understand fully the question...

Answer (score 424):

Here's a quick jQuery example that adds a click event to each "li" tag, and then retrieves the class attribute for the clicked element.

```
$("li").click(function() {
   var myClass = $(this).attr("class");
   alert(myClass);
});
```

Equally, you don't have to wrap the object in jQuery:

```
$("li").click(function() {
   var myClass = this.className;
   alert(myClass);
});
```

And in newer browsers you can get the [full list of class names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList):

```
$("li").click(function() {
   var myClasses = this.classList;
   alert(myClasses.length + " " + myClasses[0]);
});
```

You can emulate `classList` in older browsers using `myClass.split(/\s+/);`

Comment: "class" is not a valid variable name.

Comment: One of those funny situations where jQuery is the long way. this.className will give you the same as $(this).attr("class")

Comment: what if the element has more than one class name?

Comment: Not sure why but the 2nd example can't retrieve the class name for me.
However, the 1st example works great!
Thanks!  Helped me a ton.  :)

Answer (score 39):

```
$("li").click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr("class"));
});
```

Answer (score 32):

I saw this question so I thought I might expand on it a little more. This is an expansion of the idea that @SteveFenton had. Instead of binding a `click` event to each `li` element, it would be more efficient to delegate the events from the `ul` down.

**For jQuery 1.7 and higher**

```
$("ul.tabs").on('click', 'li', function(e) {
   alert($(this).attr("class"));
});
```

*Documentation:* [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

**For jQuery 1.4.2 - 1.7**

```
$("ul.tabs").delegate('li', 'click', function(e) {
   alert($(this).attr("class"));
});
```

*Documentation:* [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

**As a last resort for jQuery 1.3 - 1.4**

```
$("ul.tabs").children('li').live('click', function(e) {
   alert($(this).attr("class"));
});
```

or

```
$("ul.tabs > li").live('click', function(e) {
   alert($(this).attr("class"));
});
```

*Documentation:* [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Answer (score 18):

This should do the trick:

```
...
select: function(event, ui){ 
   ui.tab.attr('class');
} ,
...
```

For more info about the ui.tab see http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#Events

Comment: What does this mean? Could you explain that more?

Comment: It's ui.tab instead of ui.item you need to use. I thought it was ui.item.

Answer (score 15):

All the solutions provided force you to *know the element you will click beforehand*. If you want to get the class from **any element clicked** you can use:

```
$(document).on('click', function(e) {
    clicked_id = e.target.id;
    clicked_class = $('#' + e.target.id).attr('class');
    // do stuff with ids and classes 
    })
```

Comment: It should be noted that if getting an id is unreliable, one can always use `$(e.target)` instead of `$('#' + e.target.id)` and jQuery will still handle this case reasonably.

Answer (score 9):

```
$("div").click(function() {
  var txtClass = $(this).attr("class");
  console.log("Class Name : "+txtClass);
});
```