# get class name with jquery

Tags: jquery

Inside the div element set within variable called $target I have elements with single class.
I want to pass throw each element and get its class name.
Something like this:

```
$.each($target.children(), function(){
    //get class from 'this' - how?
});
```

What is the best way to do so?

I don't want to do it using classic JavaScript (.className)!

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery - get class of clicked li element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/964119/jquery-get-class-of-clicked-li-element)

Comment: It is not duplication. Different questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use attr function.
e.g.

```
$.each($target.children(), function(){
    alert($(this).attr("class"))
});
```

Comment: Does it returns array of class names or single string with the class names?

Comment: It will retirn single string with class names.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it that handles multiple classes per element, returns a list of classes without duplicates, and should work across browsers (using `$.inArray` instead of `indexOf`).

```
function getUniqueClasses(jqobj) {
  var result = [];
  jqobj.each(function(idx, elem) {
    $.each(elem.className.split(' '), function(i, e) {
      if ($.inArray(e, result) == -1) result.push(e);
    });
  });
  return result.join(','); // if you want a list instead of an array
}
```

Then:

```
var answer = getUniqueClasses( $('#target').children() );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each($target.children(), function(){
    var cls = $(this).attr("class");
});
```