# get the class of all the element inside the div

Tags: jquery

Ok. I want to get all the class names of a div inside the main div.

How to do it that to get all the class of div that inside in a div??

for example:

```
<div id="themaindiv">
    <div class="div1"></div>
    <div class="div2"></div>
    <div class="div3"></div>
</div>
```

now, i want to get all the class names of all the div which is inside the div named "themaindiv" but i just dont know how to done it.

update: and then display those class names which been hook by the function into the specified div ('#theclassnames').

example of the result that should be.

```
<div id="theclassnames">div1 div2 div3 div4</div>
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/964119/jquery-get-class-of-clicked-li-element

Comment: There are no id's inside a div in your HTML.

Comment: @hakre: comn, it just a little mistake, please do it with common sense. sorry my bad, it should be a class sorry, i edited it anyway.

Comment: @user1292042: That's better, as you can see that's the exact duplicate of the other question. Maybe you have also searched with the wrong terms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#themaindiv div").each(function(){
    alert($(this).attr("class"));
});
```

Comment: nice, but how to make it to display those class names?

Comment: You want to display all the class in another div ??

Comment: yes, could it be done? like display it like this <div id="theclassnames">div1 div2 div3 div4</div>

Comment: $("#themaindiv div").each(function(){
    $("#theclassnames").append($(this).attr("class"));
});

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you mean you want to get an array of the class names of each `div` that is a descendant of `#themaindiv`, you can use [`map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) to obtain the class name of each element, and [`get`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) to obtain an array:

```
var arrayOfClassNames = $("#themaindiv div").map(function() {
    return this.className;
}).get();
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/xSVTJ/).

---

Some notes:

- It's quicker to use a normal CSS selector e.g. `#themaindiv div` than it is to use the `find` method as is done in some of the other answers.
- It's quicker to use the native `className` property than it is to pass `this` to jQuery and use the `attr` or `prop` methods.
- If you don't care that you end up with an instance of jQuery instead of a native Array, you can omit the call to `get`.

---

**Update**

Apparently you now want to display these class names in another `div`. The easiest way is to simply use the `text` method and pass in the array:

```
$("#theclassnames").text(arrayOfClassNames);
```

That will set the text content of `#theclassnames` to the string representation of that array. In your case that would be "div1,div2,div3". You can [see it in action here](http://jsfiddle.net/xSVTJ/3/).

To display it exactly as you have now shown in your question, you can simply `join` the array with spaces:

```
$("#theclassnames").text(arrayOfClassNames.join(" ");
```

And here's [another working example](http://jsfiddle.net/xSVTJ/4/).

Comment: Don't you feel you start to replicate the jQuery manual here?

Comment: Yeah, sometimes I do. I'm so used to typing these answers that I find it quicker to just type it than find the right page in the jQuery docs and post a comment.

Comment: What's the problem ? It's informative, true, and useful for OP, isn't it ?

Comment: Well I can't speak for OP actually, OP probably has other problems so even such a nice written answer might not help him. But @JamesAllardice you might want to join the jQuery documentation team if you have fun improving stuff.

Comment: hey this is nice, but how about to display those class names?

Comment: @user1292042 - That wasn't part of your question. Display them however you like! This gets you an array of them that you can iterate over and use any way you like.

Comment: @hakre - Thanks :) That is definitely something that would interest me, if I had the time to do it! Maybe I'll look into it one day.

Comment: @user1292042 - I've updated my answer with a possible method for you to display the class names.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$('#themaindiv div').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).attr('class'));
})
```

Comment: how about to display those class names which been hook with that function from the main div?

Answer (score 0):

```
var classes = [];

$('#themaindiv').find('div').each(function(){
    classes.push(this.className);
});
```

To display them, you could add another div :

```
   <div id=theclassnames></div>
```

And do something like

```
$('#theclassnames').html(classes.join(' '));
```

But most js coders would simply do `console.log(classes);`

Comment: lolz 2 seconds different although glad we are both bit different :)

Comment: how about to display those class names which been hook with that function from the main div?

Answer (score 0):

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/Fb3bN/11/

**code**

```
$('#themaindiv').find('div').each(function(){
    alert($(this).prop('class'));
});​
```

Comment: nice but how to display it not using alert instead using of a div to display those class names?

Answer (score 0):

```
var arrayOfClassNames = [];
$("#themaindiv div").attr('class', function() {
  arrayOfClassNames.push(this.className);
});
console.log(arrayOfClassNames);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xSVTJ/2/)**

Comment: how about to display those class names which been hook with that function from the main div?