# How to get the class of a div on click

Tags: jquery

I have following div structure

```
<div class="mainDiv">
    <div class="subDiv01">
    </div>
    <div class="subDiv02">
    </div>
    <div class="subDiv03">
    </div>
    <div class="subDiv04">
    </div>
</div>
```

how could i know the subDiv's are clicked?
please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery - get class of clicked li element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/964119/jquery-get-class-of-clicked-li-element)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
$('.mainDiv div').click(function(){
    var className = $(this).attr('class');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ewijej/1/edit)**

```
$('.mainDiv').find('div').click(function(){
    alert( this.className );
});
```