# Search for partial class name, return full class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Picture this:

Page A contains this in the `body`:

```
<div class="overlay-homepage"><span></span></div>
```

Page B contains:

```
<div class="overlay-results"><span></span></div>
```

I can use this script to identify if they contain an overlay class with this:

```
function() {
    var htmlString = $('body').html().toString();
    var index = htmlString.indexOf("div class=\"overlay-");
    if (index != -1)
        return("It works");
}
```

For the return value, instead of "It works", how do I get it to pull in the rest of the class name e.g. "overlay-results" or if needs be the whole `div` content e.g. "`<div class="overlay-results"><span></span></div>`"?

There are many other pages like this with different 'overlay-' class names so I don't want to do one search for each hence this 'one size fits all' approach.

Comment: Hi, I think this question and the selected answer can probably help you with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/964119/how-to-get-the-class-of-the-clicked-element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a regular expression and rewrite it like this:

```
function() {
  var htmlString = $('body').html().toString();
  var matches = htmlString.match(/class="(overlay-[^\s"]*)/);
  if (matches.length)
    return(matches[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [this](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) jQuery selector, for example

This will give you elements which has `overlay` somewhere on their class name.

`$('div[class*=overlay]')`

This will give you elements which class name starts with `overlay`.

`$('td[class^=overlay]')`

This will give you elements which class name ends with `overlay`.

`$('td[class$=overlay]')`

EDIT:

To use this on your code you can do something like:

```
function() {
  var attr = $('div[class*=overlay]').attr('class');
  return(attr);
});
```

This function fi
nd the elements with overlay in their class name a returns the complete class name.

Comment: @aphextwig I've edited my answer to add the function.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a vanilla JS solution.

Return all class names that **contain** the substring `overlay` :

```
document.querySelectorAll( '[ class*="overlay" ]' )
```

And two extras:

Return all class names that **start with** the substring `overlay` :

```
document.querySelectorAll( '[ class^="overlay" ]' )
```

Return all class names that **end with** the substring `overlay` :

```
document.querySelectorAll( '[ class$="overlay" ]' )
```

Explanation:
`*=` `^=` and `$=` are [CSS attribute selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp):

- `*=` Search for substring anywhere
- `^=` Search for substring at the start
- `$=` Search for substring at the end

The meaning of `^` and `$` attribute selectors are congruent with their meaning in regex.

Answer (score 2):

To select an element which **starts** with, use `^` like `[class^="overlay-"]`.

To return all elements with that starting `class`, you can:-

```
function allOverlays() {
   // all elements
   return $('div[class^="overlay-"]');

   //or for the first element
   return $('div[class^="overlay-"]:eq(0)');
}
```

or to return the class when there is only one, you can use:-

```
function overlayClass() {
   return $('div[class^="overlay-"]:eq(0)').attr('class');
}
```

or when there are multi classes, use:-

```
function overlayClass() {
   var classes = $('div[class^="overlay-"]:eq(0)').attr('class');
   return /overlay-\w+/.exec(classes)[0];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you want the **full class** that matches the overlay, and not the value of the attribute class for the element. By doing a partial attribute search with a selector we can get all elements that match that search, then iterate through them, extracting from their classes the ones that match the give partial class.

```
function getFullClass(partialClass) {
    foundClasses = [];
    $("[class*='" + partialClass + "']").each(function (i, e) {
        foundClasses.push($(e).attr("class").split(" ").filter(function (d) {
            return d.indexOf(partialClass) >= 0
        }));
    });
    return foundClasses;
}

//Callable like:
getFullClass("overlay-");
```

Would output: `[overlay-homepage,overlay-results]` or whatever is on page, if you only want one result, you can simply do `getFullClass("overlay-")[0]`

Answer (score 0):

Simple use `.find()` in jquery.

> Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched
>   elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

```
$(function() {
  if($('body').find("[class^='overlay-']").length) {
    alert('it works');
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks but how does it return the full class name?

Answer (score 0):

Using the SMACSS Methodology (https://smacss.com/book/) you can modularize  different areas of your site based on the layout and structure. The layout of the page gets top level classes which apply basic and generic styles and any page specific styles are applied through name-spaced classes. For instance all overlays have the `.ovr` class which indicates it's an overlay and `.ovr-homepage`, `.ovr-results` classes would apply and unique styles.

You can than get all overlay modules with `$('body .ovr');` or specific overlays with `$('body .ovr-homepage');` or `$('body .ovr.ovr-homepage');`.

Instead of overcomplicating it with JS it can be solved with CSS structure and organization.