# Javascript classList search with partial class name, return full class name

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript i have a classList:

```
0: "content"
1: "htmlBody"
2: "needTranslation-biblio"
```

i search with partial class = 'needTranslation' and i need a result = needTranslation-biblio

I'm already look on this link but no one of this works for me and i need on Javascript not JQuery:

[Search for partial class name, return full class name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33920402/search-for-partial-class-name-return-full-class-name)

Comment: What have you tried? What does your current (non-working) code look like?

Comment: @Luke i need to search with partial class on the classList, i need to have a result the full class, as i wrote i test different way, but with no good result, i try also this element.classList.contains(/needTranslation/) but the result it is false

Answer (score 0):

Solution

```
for (var i=0, l=spanElement[k].classList.length; i<l; ++i) {
        if(/needTranslation-.*/.test(spanElement[k].classList[i])) {
          console.log("spanElement ----- needTranslation", spanElement[k].classList[i])
            break;
        }
    }
```