# Jquery get class selector name from multiple selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do you get the clicked selector class from multiple selectors?

```
<div class="login ab xy yz">Login</div>
<div class="register po rt">Register</div>
<div class="lostpw ad op">Lost Password</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('click','.login , .register , .lostpw',function(){
        var class_selected = 'login' /* way to find which class selector is clicked , suppose "login"*/
        openForm(class_selected);
    })
</script>
```

I am working on a library , so i have to consider all the scenarios.
1) Classes can be in any order. 
2) Cannot use a common class.

[Duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964119/how-to-get-the-class-of-the-clicked-element) here is for a single class so ,most of the answers are `$(this).attr('class')` which i am aware of.

Comment: Related: [How to get the class of the clicked element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964119/how-to-get-the-class-of-the-clicked-element)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the class of the clicked element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964119/how-to-get-the-class-of-the-clicked-element)

Comment: Thats a different case.

Comment: @wordpressuser please modify your question explaining why it is a different case. Maybe it is not clear for most users.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one common class & then use [**hasclass**](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) jquery method

```js
$(document).on('click', '.home', function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass('login')) {
    console.log('login')
  } else if ($(this).hasClass('register')) {
    console.log('register')
  } else if ($(this).hasClass('iflostpw')) {
    console.log('iflostpw')
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="home login ab xy yz">Login</div>
<div class="home register po rt">Register</div>
<div class="home iflostpw ad op">Lost Password</div>
```

Comment: Also no reason to rebuild the jQuery object each time, just do `let $this = $(this);` before you start using it in the if statements.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an array of selectors, pass them to your event handler and then use them inside to determine which was clicked:

```
var selectors = [
  '.login',
  '.register',
  '.lostpw'
];

$( document ).on( 'click', selectors.join( ',' ), function( evt ) {

  var $this = $( this );

  var clicked = $.grep( selectors, function( selector ) {
    return $this.is( selector );
  } ).shift();

  console.log( clicked ); // .substr(1) to remove the leading .

} );
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oth6fs9r/)