# How to get alert of class name from selected option in select tag using jquery?

Tags: javascript

I have a `<select>` tag with all options that are coming from the database. What I want to happen is when I select on a particular option, I want to get class name, but I am getting `Undefined` when I do it this way. Why is this happening?

**HTML**:

```
<select id="mySelect"  class="form-control get-this">
    <?php
             foreach ($res as $r) {
             ?>

      <option class="<?= $r->item_name ?>" ><?= $r->item_name ?></option>


              <?php }
            ?>

       </select>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
<script>
       $('.get-this').on('change', function() { 
    var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
    var valueSelected = $('option:selected').attr('class'); 

alert($(this).find('option:selected').attr("class"));

}); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the class name of an element, use JavaScript's `.className` property.

Syntax:

```
object.className
```

Example:

```
console.log(document.querySelector("#element").className);
```

For multiple classes, use `classList` (only in newer versions):

```
// Gets fourth class
console.log(document.querySelector("#element").classList[3];
```

To emulate `classList` in older versions, use `.split(/\s+/)`

```
// Gets fourth class
console.log(document.querySelector("#element").className.split(/\+s/)[3];
```

Source: [How to get class of clicked element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964119/how-to-get-the-class-of-the-clicked-element)

**Edit:**
@Andreas was right. The code you have already works and it dosen't need to be modified.

```
console.log($("#element").attr("class"));
```

```js
$("#js").text(document.querySelector("#element").className);
$("#jq").text($("#element").attr("class"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="element" class="my-class"></div>

<code>.className</code> returns: <span id="js"></span><br>
<code>.attr("class")</code> returns: <span id="jq"></span>
```

Comment: @Anonymous Why is this the accepted answer when the problem was an obvious typo? The script in the question works when fixing the typo.

Comment: @Andreas There is no typo in the code. The only typo is in your comment.

Comment: There was a typo which was the only problem, but TO has edited the question and removed the typo and the problem.